# Defining an abstract service with multiple implementations

Tags: docker, docker-compose

In a Docker Compose setup, which I use for development and testing, I have a backend service and different storage services (MongoDB, PostgreSQL). The backend needs exactly one storage service, it can be be configured to use either one. For convenience, I'd like to use profiles, but I'm open to other approaches as well.

What I tried is roughly this (which doesn't work unfortunately):

```yaml
services:
  backend:
    build: .
    depends_on:
      storage:
        condition: service_healthy

  # abstract service
  storage: {}

  # MongoDB storage implementation
  mongodb:
    extends: storage
    image: mongo:4.4
    profiles:
      - mongodb-storage

  postgresql:
    extends: storage
    image: postgres:13.8
    profiles:
      - postgresql-storage
```

The approach here is to use Docker Compose profiles to select the storage. The problem here is that the "storage" service can't be started, it lacks mandatory settings. I also don't want it to be started but expect one of the two derived services to be started instead and to provide the "storage" service.

I can exclude the "storage" service by putting it into a separate profile. That then causes it not to be started (as I'd like), but the derived services don't "pick up" and startup fails due to a missing dependency.

Instead of using one "backend" service, I could use one for each storage service and pair them into separate profiles. Problem here is that with just every service with multiple implementations, the number of actual service definitions multiplies by the number of implementations. In other words, it scales badly.

I could probably use variable substitution ("interpolation") in the compose file in order to achieve this, but I'd call that clumsy. The reason is that these things are hard to explore, other than a profile which implicitly documents "here is something optional you can select".

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you can use `profiles:` and `extends:` in this combination.  `extends:` creates a new Compose service that reuses some of the definitions from the original one, but it's not an object-oriented "this is an instance of" relationship.

The [documentation on Compose profiles](https://docs.docker.com/compose/profiles/) indicates that you can use profiles to selectively enable or disable services, but then a `depends_on:` relationship always brings the referenced services with it.  There's no way to say that `storage` could be either of two things, or further to indicate that different environment variables should be set based on the profile.

This is a setup where [multiple Compose files](https://docs.docker.com/compose/multiple-compose-files/) can work well.  With this setup, the base `docker-compose.yml` file would contain only the service itself, with no storage backend at all

```yaml
# docker-compose.yml
version: '3.8'
services:
  backend:
    build: .
```

You can then write a separate Compose file for each storage backend.  In this you'd add the `depends_on:` setting and any required environment variables, but not the base image itself.

```yaml
# docker-compose.postgresql.yaml
version: '3.8'
services:
  backend: # same name
    # no build:, image:, ports:, other things defined in base YAML
    environment:
      STORAGE_BACKEND: postgresql
      POSTGRES_HOST: postgresql
  postgresql:
    image: postgres:13.8
    # etc.
```

The easiest way to "activate" this is to set the [`COMPOSE_FILE` environment variable](https://docs.docker.com/compose/environment-variables/envvars/#compose_file) to reference both files.  You can do it with `docker-compose -f` options, but you need to remember to provide the options to *every* `docker-compose` invocation.

```bash
export COMPOSE_FILE=docker-compose.yml:docker-compose.postgresql.yaml
docker-compose up -d
```

If you're using a current version of Compose (`docker compose` with no hyphen works) then you might be able to use the [`include:`](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/14-include/) syntax to simplify this

```yaml
# compose.yml
# Does not work with Compose 1.x
version: '4.x'
include:
  - path:
      - compose.main.yml
      - compose.${STORAGE_BACKEND:-postgresql}.yaml
```

Comment: Just out of curiousity, do you know of a good use case for the `extends` feature? To me, this seems similar to deriving from a concrete class in OOP, which is more of an antipattern.

Comment: Say you want to use only the `compose.postgresql.yaml` file.  Instead of depending on getting the base definition of the `backend` service from a second loaded Compose file, it could use `extends:` to explicitly reference the other file to get the definition.  The more typical use case for this functionality is to provide extra port and service definitions for a developer-oriented setup.